# JSON search API for finding Android apps (on Android Market and elsewhere)?

Tags: android, google-play

iTunes offers a JSON API for searching against app names (e.g., find all apps named, "Yelp").

We can't seem to find the equivalent for Android Market or other Android marketplaces. Does this exist?

The ideal API would let us search for any Android app, even if it's listed on Amazon and not on the Android Market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to find one. The various Android app aggregation sites (androidpit, androlib, androidzoom etc) may offer one that feeds off the various markets, but there is no unified API that documents all Android apps regardless of distribution channel (the same way there is no unified API that documents all iOS apps on iTunes and Cydia).

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ is an api for the market that supports searches. It may provide a meaningful start.

Answer (score 5):

## Update

**This service was shut down**, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-play-scraper

---

Use the [WhereDat](http://wheredatapp.com/developers/) API:

http://api.wheredatapp.com/search?q=term

result:

```
{
    apps: [
        {
        category: "Tools",
        rating: 4.409321308135986,
        updated: 1431698203,
        created: 1431082225,
        icon_url: "https://lh4.ggpht.com/2jbUS9Hz8nWQEZKQR17xpxEnXhlW3tisxmhi-NNrMaA6TQT2RtewoHAezDXCbEPJxg=w300",
        title: "Terminal Emulator for Android",
        download_url: "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm",
        package: "jackpal.androidterm",
        ratings_count: 81873,
        short_description: "Access your Android&#39;s built-in Linux command line shell. Unleash your inner geek!This is a new version of the popular &quot;Android Terminal Emulator&quot; applica..."
        }
]}
```

Comment: Any references to it's documentation?

Comment: @zack - right here: http://wheredatapp.com/developers

Comment: This is neat. And exactly what I was looking for. Can I use it in my production app? How often does the service break?

Comment: @zack great, definitely use it in production, it never breaks :) feel free to contact support, there's an email at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Broken link, maybe project is dead!